Use of a DC motor in conjunction with a TP4056 module and a lion battery
I have a very old battery powered dremel. Its design is simple, it consists out of three blocks:
Motor - Swtich - Battery
The original NiMH battery pack is dead and I replaced it with a single 18650 Lion battery. To modernize things and to ensure a good battery life I added a USBC charging PCB, namely the TP4056 (data + schematic).
Now, when I flip the switch the motor does not always turn on. It does a quarter of a turn and stops. I am looking for the reason why and how to fix this.
I tested the motor with a lab bench supply at 4.2V and the current draw is around 0.4A.
I have replaced the rocker switch with an identical one and it has increased the chances of turning it on noticeably. Next I used very thin wires as a switch and 9/10 times it would turn on. My assumption is that flipping the switch creates some sort of voltage spike that triggers the safety mechanism in the TP4056 module and clean contacts or thin wires limit the current rush. Could that be it?

What is the specification for the original battery pack?
